# Callback function is not executed with ondestroy

Tags: python, gtk, glade

I'm developing an application using python gtk+ and glade. My glade file format is gtk-builder. I've two windows in it - one main window and one login window. Inside __ init __ () I **run** the login dialog window, so that I can make sure the focus will not be switched to the main window until the user emits **OK** signal from the login window. When this is done using the following code, the user has to click twice on the **[x]** on the titlebar, to quit the application. When I use loginWindow.show() rather than the run(), it works perfect, but the focus issue arises there. How can I fix this issue?

```
import sys
try:
    import pygtk
    pygtk.require("2.8")
except:
    pass
try:
    import gtk
except:
    sys.exit(1)


class netChat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file("netchat.glade")
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)
        self.loginWindow = self.builder.get_object('loginWindow')
        self.mainWindow = self.builder.get_object('mainWindow')
        self.message = self.builder.get_object('message')
        self.timeLine = self.builder.get_object('timeLine')
        self.loginWindow.run()
    def onSend(self, widget):
        text = self.message.get_text()
        myBuffer = self.timeLine.get_buffer()
        myBuffer.insert_at_cursor(' '+text+'\n')
        self.message.set_text('')
        print "on Send"
    def mainQuit(self, widget):
        print "Quiting, goodbye!"
        sys.exit(0)
    def loginQuit(self, widget):
        print "Login Quit, goodbye!"
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myChat = netChat()
    gtk.main()
```

I tried setting the same mainQuit() callback for both of the windows too. But that didn't make any difference. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a reentry issue. Probably you are running the main window from the onClick of the "ok" button in the login dialog.

Maybe you are calling `gtk.main()` several times?

It is difficult to guess, since your code is not complete.

Comment: No I was not running the main window from the onClick() of the login "OK". Both of the windows pops up at the same time, but the login window only has focus before log in. And code is complete, should I post the glade file too?
Thanks